CakePHP 4 JSON response gives phpstan error
According to the CakePHP 4 docs
// If you want a json response
$response = $response->withType('application/json')
->withStringBody(json_encode(['Foo' => 'bar']));

If you run phpstan on level 7 it will give this error

Parameter #1 $string of method Cake\Http\Response::withStringBody() expects string|null, string|false given.

json_encode is a core PHP function which has return types string|false so can't be modified.
withStringBody() is a CakePHP core method which accepts string|null.
How can you get around that error since neither of those 2 things can be modified directly?

You could try casting the result of the function call to string (string)json_encode()

Do the json_encode first, on an earlier line, and if it returns false, don't pass it to withStringBody. If it does return false it indicates a problem with the encoding so I'd have thought you'd want to detect that and log an error and so on anyway. You can also set json-throw-on-error to make it automatically throw an exception when it fails, rather than having to detect it.
